# extract information from a data frame parametrically (via a menu selection)

Tags: r

I would like to extract information from a data frame parametrically.
That is:

```
A <- c(3, 10, 20, 30, 40)
B <- c(30, 100, 200, 300, 400)
DF <- data.frame(A, B)

DF[A%in%c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), ] # it works

# But what if this is the case,
# which comes for example out of a user-menu selection:
m <- "A%in%"
k <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)

# How can we make something like that work:
DF[eval(parse(text=c(m, k))), ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
DF[eval(parse(text = paste0(m, deparse(k)))), ]
#  A  B
#1 3 30
```

However, `eval(parse())` should be avoided. Maybe this would be an alternative for you?

```
x <- "A"
fun <- "%in%"
k <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
DF[getFunction(fun)(get(x), k), ]
#  A  B
#1 3 30
```

Answer (score 2):

Also,

```
DF[eval(parse(text=paste(m, substitute(k)))),]
```

or

```
DF[eval(parse(text=paste(m, quote(k)))),]
```

or

```
DF[eval(parse(text=paste(m, "k"))),]
```